# How to create a cardboard .vr.jpg file in Windows Shell (DOS batch script) using ffmpeg and exiftool?

Tags: image-processing, google-cardboard

Starting from [this incredibly complex script](https://github.com/abakum/vr.jpg/blob/main/LR2VR.bat) I am trying to write a stripped down version which just creates a .vr.jpg file starting from one single equirectangular full panorama 360x180, but the resulting image:

- does not look good in [this carboard viewer](https://vr.caffeinum.com/create.html)
- does not load at all in the [official cardboard converter](http://storage.googleapis.com/cardboard-camera-converter/index.html)
- shows fine in [this viewer](https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/guide/cropped-panorama.html#playground)

It should be "just" a matter of [writing six EXIF/XMP tags in the file](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata?hl=it), plus one EXIF/XMP tag containing the image for right eye; my script does all of this.... but it actually does not work.

Any idea?

If I understand correctly [this image](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata?hl=it)...

[image: photosphere]

...values of tags for a full sphere should be:

1. CroppedAreaLeftPixels = 0
2. CroppedAreaTopPixels = 0
3. CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels = Image Width
4. CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels = Image Height
5. FullPanoWidthPixels = Image Width
6. FullPanoHeightPixels = Image Height

But nor this neither other combinations work.

Ideas?

The script:

```
set R=%~n1.vr.jpg
set O=%~n1-cardboard.vr.jpg

:mpo
call :set                                                     ImageWidthR ImageHeightR
exiftool -s2 -ImageWidth -ImageHeight "%R%"

for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq delims=: " %%i in (`exiftool -s2 -ImageWidth -ImageHeight "%R%"`) do set %%i=%%j




set /a FullPanoWidthPixels=ImageWidth
set /a FullPanoHeightPixels=ImageHeight

set /a CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels=ImageWidth
set /a CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels=ImageHeight

set /a CroppedAreaLeftPixels=0
set /a CroppedAreaTopPixels=ImageHeight/2



exiftool -XMP-GPano:all^
 -XMP-GPano:UsePanoramaViewer="True"^
 -XMP-GPano:CroppedAreaLeftPixels="%CroppedAreaLeftPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:CroppedAreaTopPixels="%CroppedAreaTopPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels="%CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels="%CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:FullPanoWidthPixels="%FullPanoWidthPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:FullPanoHeightPixels="%FullPanoHeightPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:ProjectionType="equirectangular"^
 -XMP-GPano:LargestValidInteriorRectLeft="0"^
 -XMP-GPano:LargestValidInteriorRectTop="0"^
 -XMP-GPano:LargestValidInteriorRectWidth="%FullPanoWidthPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:LargestValidInteriorRectHeight="%FullPanoHeightPixels%"^
 -XMP-GPano:InitialHorizontalFOVDegrees="50"^
                -XMP-GImage:"ImageMimeType=image/jpeg"^
                -XMP-GImage:"ImageData<=%~n1.vr.jpg" ^
 %~n1.vr.jpg


goto :eof

:set
 @if "%1"=="" goto :EOF
 @set %1=
 @shift
@goto :set
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography and would probably be better suited at [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MichaelC I'm not expressing an opinion if this is off-topic or not, but if anywhere else, it seems that maybe [su] might be the appropriate place instead of GD-SE? (Really not sure here)

Comment: what do you mean "it is not about photography"? What do you think a .vr.jpg cardboard file is? This section has also a specific tag for questions like this: "image-processing", already used in 230 questions.. Anyway the question already has its final answer, tomorrow I'll accept it and that'sall.